# Determine if a point lies between two others on an arc parameterization without trig operations

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Suppose we are given the points $\{u, v, w\}$ on an arc.  The arc starts at $u$ in the direction indicated by the blue vector, and terminates once it has reached all three points.  We also know the center of the arc.

[image: Illustration of arc direction]

The goal is to determine if the arc passes through $v$ before reaching $w$.  Example A satisfies this condition; example B doesn't.

I know I can do this with an inverse tangent operation.  But is there any way to compute it without using a trig function?

Comment: How is the arc specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n$ be a vector perpendicular to $u-w$. Check if $$\langle \text{blue vector},n\rangle\cdot \langle v-u,n\rangle\ge 0.$$

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can also do it with calculus as well.

check if length of curve [uw] > length of curve [uv]

[curve length](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_geometry_of_curves#Length_and_natural_parametrization)